# Referencing documents with @DBRef annotation on a Set

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following class, which is a part of a larger domain structure. In other words, `Squad` is not the base of the document:

```
public class Squad {

  @DBRef
  private final Set<Player> players;

  public Squad(Set<Player> players) {
    this.players = ImmutableSet.copyOf(Objects.requireNonNull(players));
  }

  public Set<Player> getPlayers() {
    return players;
  }

}
```

How `Player` looks should not be relevant for the question.

I am using [Spring Data MongoDB](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/) version *1.10.1*, which allows me to use [`@DBRef`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/DBRef.html) to reference `Player`s as separate documents.

To store and read the documents I am extending [`MongoRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html).

I have no problems storing the documents, but when reading them from the database, Spring Data tries to create `Squad` using a `List` constructor.

I try to keep my domain clean, and since a squad should contain unique players, a `Set` makes sence. Also I would like to avoid cluttering my classes with constructors (for example default constructors), only to make this work. As a side note, I am trying to keep my domain immutable.

**How can I make Spring Data MongoDB understand how to instantiate `Squad` with a set of `Player`s when reading it from the database?** Or is this just the way MongoDB works? (I am more familiar with relational databases/JPA, where a `Set` could be used like this)

I guess letting the constructor accept `Collection` as argument could work, but as I said I'd like to avoid that. I also tried using a private constructor taking in a `Collection`, but then Spring Data expected a no arguments constructor (I guess because  two constructors where found).

---

Perhaps not relevant, but this is the stacktrace I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:83) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:257) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:237) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1214) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:84) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1162) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1125) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:78) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:71) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:83) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:257) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:237) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1214) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:84) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1162) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1125) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:78) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:71) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:83) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:257) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:237) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:197) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:193) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:84) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:2313) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1966) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1784) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1767) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:641) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:359) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:197) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:51) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at my.package.TestController.getAllTeams(TestController.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

And what my test controller returns:

```json
{
  "timestamp": 1491657302229,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException",
  "message": "Failed to instantiate my.package.team.Squad using constructor public my.package.team.Squad(java.util.Set) with arguments [my.package.person.player.Player@2afde45b, my.package.person.player.Player@7f87e2e6, my.package.person.player.Player@337d278d, my.package.person.player.Player@3637e725, my.package.person.player.Player@732d0284, my.package.person.player.Player@337d5ed5, my.package.person.player.Player@69665678, my.package.person.player.Player@60e19abe, my.package.person.player.Player@7b439d04, my.package.person.player.Player@2211ef4f, my.package.person.player.Player@799fb8e3, my.package.person.player.Player@1547f904, my.package.person.player.Player@728bed15, my.package.person.player.Player@5fcd1f9c, my.package.person.player.Player@5b91ec26, my.package.person.player.Player@7134b189, my.package.person.player.Player@5cfa19ff, my.package.person.player.Player@6bfcdc03, my.package.person.player.Player@3fd8fd86, my.package.person.player.Player@6bb4ab0d]",
  "path": "/club"
}
```

Comment: Both field based and setter based injection work fine and are converted  to `Set<Player>`  using spring's collection converter.This will not help you with immutable part. Looks like code relevant for the bean creation (constructor based injection) is bulk fetching DBRef into List and later passing it for bean creation and in the process losing the target type `Set`. You can create a jira here if you like. https://jira.spring.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: I could be wrong, but you may need it to be a List because indexing and sorting may be needed by Spring Mongo DB implementation. If you really want a Set, your only option may be to keep it as an internal implementation detail and convert to a set everywhere else.

Comment: @Veeram Your comment kind of qualifies as an answer. Did you dig into the source code and find that it always uses a list to instantiate the object?   Would a perhaps a private default constructor and a private setter (accepting `Collection<Player>`) solve the problem? Would Spring use the private constructor and the private setter to instantiate the object?

Comment: yeah I looked into code and spring is calling [DBRefResolver.fetch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/DbRefResolver.html#bulkFetch-java.util.List-) to return a list of DBRefs. You have to annotate  `@AccessType(AccessType.Type.PROPERTY)` to make spring use 
accessor method. Continue ...

Comment: So `public Set<Player> setPlayers(Set<Player> players) {
   this.players = ImmutableSet.copyOf(Objects.requireNonNull(players));
  }` works and sets the players to `RegularImmutableSet` but changing it to `private` sets the `players` to `LinkedHashSet` and method body is not called.

Comment: @Veeram Thanks, but too bad. Actually, I prefer keeping the immutability, so changing the constructor to accept a `Collection` is so far the best workaround.

Comment: You are welcome.Yes for now. I have added the jira for the issue just in case if spring team has better workaround/ fix. https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both field and property accessor mapping works fine and are converted to `Set<Player>` using spring's collection converter.

This will not help you with immutable part.

It looks like code relevant for the bean creation  is bulk fetching `DBRef` into List and later passing it for bean creation and in the process losing the target type `Set`.

The below jira has been logged to cover the change to allow collection type into constructor creation.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1666

Right now the workaround is to change constructor to accept a `Collection` type as you've already found.